# Get values changed by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to get values from a DB and change the default "0" value. But when later I try to get the values all return the default "0";

```
jQuery.post('../vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {

    jQuery('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up);

},'json');

//later
//jquery each
jquery('.up_votes').text();
// returns 0,0,0,0,0

//html
<div class="voting_wrapper" id='<?php echo $item->alias; ?>'>
    <div class="voting_btn">
        <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes">0</span>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the values after they have been changed by jquery?

Thank you

Comment: How does your markup look?

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cJ5A/. Check your console for errors.

Comment: I just updated the question with the markup.